# Can't connect to localdb

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, gitlab, localdb

Everything works on my local machine but when pushing to GitLab my runner/pipeline is having issues.

Our build step definitely looks to be creating the database (I can connect from SQL Server Management Studio when launched as NT AUTHORITY\System). But for some reason the test project can't seem to connect;

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException : The underlying provider failed on Open.
  ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot open database "test_localdb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
Data:
  HelpLink.ProdName: Microsoft SQL Server
  HelpLink.EvtSrc: MSSQLServer
  HelpLink.EvtID: 4060
  HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink
  HelpLink.LinkId: 20476
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at ConsoleApp7.Program.GetRecordById(Int32 recordId) in C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\e4c3e954\0\tel\test_localdb\ConsoleApp7\Program.cs:line 18
   at Tests.Class1.ShouldFindCustomer() in C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\e4c3e954\0\tel\test_localdb\Tests\Class1.cs:line 15
--SqlException
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__2()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
```

I have also tried to share the instance and can't connect when launching SSMS as a different using (even using the `(localdb)\.\SharedName`.

I have read a few similar questions about stopping/starting and recreating etc but to no avail. Connecting using the named pipe doesn't seem to help either.

Perhaps there is a better way to tackle this?

Comment: slight progress- I managed to create a new localdb instance and share then connect as a different user using the named pipe np:\\.\address but that's not ideal as I want to use a connection string which works both locally and on the server (i.e. `(localdb)\blah`)

Comment: okay- i think i've figured out what's happening. the database is being created in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSqlLocalDB` but the .net app is trying to load it from `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB`. Any idea how I force the connection string to point to the 32bit or 64bit instance?

Comment: Refer to restrictions section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017) : An instance of LocalDB owned by the built-in accounts such as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM can have manageability issues due to windows file system redirection. Instead use a normal windows account as the owner